# Normal order package usage

Tags: packages

I found a package that normal orders bosonic creation and annihilation operators for me. Here is the link to the package and explanation of normal ordering:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_order
https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/625/

Now I tried to normal order the expression

$$
\mathcal{N}(aa^{\dagger}aaa^{\dagger}a) = {a^{\dagger}}^{2}a^{4} + 4a^{\dagger}a^{3} + 2a^{2}
$$

with the following code having the package file installed in Mathematica

```
Needs["NormalOrdering`"]   
normalorder = NormalOrder[a ** c ** a^2 ** c ** a]
```

However, Mathematica only returns the initial expression. Now I ask myself whether I do something cardinally wrong and would be glad if someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
Philipp

Comment: Did your `Needs` command return any errors? Is `NormalOrder` blue or black in your notebook? Have you tried loading the package file with `Get` instead, e.g. `Get["C:\\path\\to\\NormalOrdering.m"]`? If I do that, then your expression produces `2 a^2 + 4 c ** a^3 + c^2 ** a^4`.

Comment: It normal-ordered correctly for me. But if I restricted the notebook's context to "unique to this notebook" then I could reproduce your problem. The relevant menu entry is Evaluation / Notebook's Default Context / Global`.

Comment: @MarcoB the `Needs` did not return any errors. Using `Get` with the path where the package is saved fixed the problem, now `NormalOrder` appears also in red color. Thank you very much guys!

Comment: You might want to just define your own bracket handling. Here is one [prior thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235304/define-commutator-of-operators-to-do-computations) along these lines.